# Open new fragment from button in view model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, navigation

I am developing a note taking app that has databinding, and all the elements of MVVM. Because I am using databinding with my button, I want to navigate to another fragment once the button is clicked from view model.

I have stored my LiveData into the variable in view model and then I am observing it in my fragment but somehow  it does not navigate to another fragment.

ViewModel.kt

`

```
private val _openScreen = MutableLiveData<String>()
val openScreen: LiveData<String> = _openScreen

fun saveButton(){


        _openScreen.value =
            "R.id.action_addUpdateNote_to_allNotesFragment"

    }
```

`

MyFragment.kt

```
    viewModel.openScreen.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(it.toInt())




    })`
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to convert string to int ! This is imposiable in your code. .toInt only can convert some string like "12", "1". And you must try converts in try catch block.

```
private val _openScreen = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val openScreen: LiveData<Int> = _openScreen

fun saveButton(){
        _openScreen.value =
            R.id.action_addUpdateNote_to_allNotesFragment
    }
```

Observe

```
viewModel.openScreen.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    findNavController()?.navigate(it)
})
```

Comment: I have tried what you have written, but its not working sadly. And I do not know how do I implement try and catch